# Special string to LocalDate

Tags: java, date, localdate

From the following String I want to get the LocalDate or LocalDateTime.

**Jan 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM**

I have already tried the following code but I am getting the following error:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); // also with dd
formatter = formatter.withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, formatter);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(stringDate, formatter);
```

- `Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jan 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM' could not be parsed at index 0`

The way I would like to have the date, in the end, would be like

- 01.01.2019. LocalDate
- 01.01.2019. 12:00 LocalDateTime (24h)

Is this even possible? Would be instead the use of regular expressions an overkill?

Comment: "which is not working" - Could you elaborate?

Comment: My bad. I get the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Jan 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: The same exception is thrown for me, but not if I remove `formatter = formatter.withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);` (I assume my `Locale` defaults to `US`).

Comment: @JacobG WFM. But I'm using Java 8. Are you using a future version? There were some locale changes in 9 that weren't entirely backwards compatible IIRC.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I'm testing it with Java 12, so it's possible.

Comment: I am running this with **jdk-11.0.1**. Nothing changed by removing the following: `formatter = formatter.withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, but I will propose a working solution here:

1. `HH` is the hour of the day, not the hour 0-12 (which is `hh`)
2. you should use a DateTimeFormatterBuilder
3. you should use the proper locale, probably `GERMANY` instead of `GERMAN`
4. the name of the month is represented as `L`, not as `M`
5. the german locale uses `vorm.` and `nachm.` instead of `AM` and `PM` -> a quick solution is to replace the terms

Putting it all together leaves us with this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stringDate = "Jan 1, 2019 11:00:00 PM";
        stringDate = stringDate.replace("AM", "vorm.");
        stringDate = stringDate.replace("PM", "nachm.");
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("LLL d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a")
                .toFormatter(Locale.GERMANY);
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, formatter);
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(stringDate, formatter);
    }

}
```

---

If anybody has a different approach to handling the `AM`/`vorm.`-dilemma, I would be glad to see it!

Comment: This works regardless of the jdk. Combined with the input from @ejdebruin `DateTimeFormatter firstOutputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.DD.YY.");
    String outputFirst = localDateTime.format(firstOutputFormat).concat(" LocalDate");` I get what I wanted from the start.

Comment: For some reason, this is not working with the following String `String stringDate = "May 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM";` I am getting the following error `Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'May 1, 2019 12:00:00 vorm.' could not be parsed at index 0` at this part `LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, formatter);`

Comment: Got it. As already mentioned from you, everything has to get translated to German. Example: `if (stringDate.contains("May")) {
            stringDate =  stringDate.replace("May","Mai");
        }`

Comment: Hey, I just read your comments. Of course `Feb` will work because it is `february` in english and `Februar` in german. Problems occur with `May` (`may` vs `Mai`) though. You had your locale set to german, which is why i thought you were parsing the german `Jan`uar. You can set your locale to english, though, then you don't even have to translate the `AM`/`PM`-part. Give me a quick response and I'll correct my answer if it's necessary.

Comment: Your answer is greate no worries. Nevertheless, I also tested it with `.toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);` and after removing `stringDate = stringDate.replace("AM", "vorm.");
        stringDate = stringDate.replace("PM", "nachm.");` it also works.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you're trying to parse a LocalDateTime format into a LocalDate.

If you have the full LocalDateTime, you shouldn't need a separate LocalDate.  If there is a need, there's also a toLocalDate() method within LocalDateTime.

```
    String stringDate = "Jan 1, 2019 12:00:00 AM";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); // also with dd
    formatter = formatter.withLocale(Locale.GERMAN);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, formatter);

    DateTimeFormatter firstOutputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.DD.YY.");
    String outputFirst = localDateTime.format(firstOutputFormat).concat(" LocalDate");

    DateTimeFormatter secondOutputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.DD.YY. HH.mm");
    String outputSecond = localDateTime.format(secondOutputFormat).concat(" LocalDateTime (24h)");
```

Comment: Your code still appears to have problems with the **jdk-11.0.1.** With **jdk1.8.0_221** everything works.

Comment: Might be due to the locale changes.  https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8202537